# Login: Busca no MySQL retorna apenas um objeto

Tags: php, mysql, while

Em um sistema de login, pego o e-mail e senha dados pelo usuário por um formulário e vejo se há quaisquer informações idênticas no banco de dados.

```
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "prisma");

        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tb_users ORDER BY iduser");
        $data = array();
        $x = -1;
        while($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            array_push($data, $row);
            $x += 1;
            if($user == $data[$x]["desusername"] && $pass == $data[$x]["despassword"]){
                if($user == $adms){
                    $_SESSION['isAdmin'] = true;
                    header('Location: index.php');
                }

                else{
                    header('Location: index.php');
                }

            }
            else{
                echo "Erro. Insira seus dados corretamente!";
                echo $data[$x]["desusername"];
                echo $data[$x]["despassword"];
                echo $user;
                echo $pass;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Sendo $user o e-mail dado pelo usuário, $pass a senha dada pelo usuário, $data[$x]["desusername"] os usuários do banco de dados e $data[$x]["despassword"] as senhas encontradas;

Porém, ao fazer o login, o $data[$x]["desusername"] e $data[$x]["despassword"] são o primeiro item do meu banco de dados, sendo que ainda tem mais um item pra percorrer!

Ex.:
O primeiro item é "t@t.com", e senha "123".
O segundo é "r@t.com" e senha "321";

Se o usuário digitar o segundo item no formulário, o meu while só terá pego o primeiro item para comparar no if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A explicação está no `break;`, reduzindo o seu código temos:

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "prisma");

```
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tb_users ORDER BY iduser");
    $data = array();
    $x = -1;
    while($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        array_push($data, $row);
        $x += 1;
        if($user == $data[$x]["desusername"] && $pass == $data[$x]["despassword"]){
           //....
        } else{
            // ...
            break;
        }
    }
```

O `break` quebrará o `while` na primeira tentativa, já que ele cairá no `else`. Isso é, você executa o `while` e na primeira verificação (que seja incorreta) cairá no `else` e este `else` dará o `break`. Por isso só executa uma única vez.

---

Ignorando outros problemas de otimização/performance e de segurança, você pode utilizar:

```
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "prisma");

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tb_users ORDER BY iduser");

    $user_found = null;    
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) && $user_found === null){
        if($user === $row["desusername"] && $pass === $row["despassword"]){
            $user_found = $row;
        }
    }

    if($user_found !== null) {
        $_SESSION['isAdmin'] = $user == $adms;
        header('Location: index.php');
        return; // early-return
    }

    echo "Erro. Insira seus dados corretamente!";
    echo $data[$x]["desusername"];
    echo $data[$x]["despassword"];
    echo $user;
    echo $pass;
```

A ideia desse código é verificar primeiro, todos as linhas, então depois fazer o que deve ser feito (dar erro ou redirecionar).

> *O `$adms` e `$user` e `$pass` não está definido, não uso PHP não posso testar.*